# How to do conditional styling (specifically a conditional className) in React-Table?

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I am using React-Table and I am trying to set the className of the `td` element of the column, but React-Table only seems to allow strings and variables for the className and NOT conditional styling.

I am using a ternary statement to select the className depending on whether the value is positive or negative, but React-Table doesn't like my syntax.

```
{
        Header: "24h Change",
        id: "market_cap_change_percentage_24h",
        className: {coin => coin.market_cap_change_percentage_24h > 0 ? "positive" : "negative"},
        accessor: coin =>
          coin.market_cap_change_percentage_24h == null
            ? coin.market_cap_change_percentage_24h
            : coin.market_cap_change_percentage_24h.toFixed(2) + "%"
      }
```

I have tried:

```
className: {coin.market_cap_change_percentage_24h > 0 ? "positive" : "negative"}
```

This:

```
className: {market_cap_change_percentage_24h > 0 ? "positive" : "negative"}
```

Even this:

```
className={market_cap_change_percentage_24h > 0 ? "positive" : "negative"}
```

And many other variations...

It tells me there's a syntax error and doesn't allow me to compile. I think I'm going about it all the wrong way, and after reading through React-Table's documentation I'm still not sure how to solve it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Seems like it doesnt like the curly braces since you're able to define accessor using javascript without any problems, Try: market_cap_change_percentage_24h > 0 ? "positive" : "negative"

Answer (score 5):

I solved the problem:

```
{
        Header: "24h Change",
        id: "market_cap_change_percentage_24h",
        Cell: coin => (
          <span className={coin.value > 0 ? "positive" : "negative"}>
            {coin.value}%
          </span>
        ),
        accessor: coin =>
          coin.market_cap_change_percentage_24h == null
            ? coin.market_cap_change_percentage_24h
            : coin.market_cap_change_percentage_24h.toFixed(2)
      }
```

Basically I used `Cell:` instead of `className:` and then used `.value` instead of `.market_cap_change_percentage_24h` and lastly I removed the `"%"` I had at the end of my accessor and put it in the Cell instead.

The React-Table docs mostly helped, as well as plenty of trial and error. Hopefully this question and answer can help others having this problem in the future.